# Jenkins Pipeline - executing job in docker permissions issues

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that looks like

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'myartifactory/cloud-eng/sls-build:0.13'
            label 'docker'
            registryUrl 'https://myartifactory'
            registryCredentialsId 'artfifactory-cred-id'
        }
    }

    environment {
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            sh "env | sort"
            sh "make setup-ci"
            sh "make test"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I see that jenkins executed a command that looks like:

```
docker run -t -d -u 1318244366:1318464184 -w /jenkins_home/jenkins-rh7-a01/8b13f8c3/workspace/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https -v /jenkins_home/jenkins-rh7-a01/8b13f8c3/workspace/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https:/jenkins_home/jenkins-rh7-a01/8b13f8c3/workspace/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https:rw,z -v /jenkins_home/jenkins-rh7-a01/8b13f8c3/workspace/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https@tmp:/jenkins_home/jenkins-rh7-a01/8b13f8c3/workspace/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ********  myartifactory/cloud-eng/sls-build:0.13 cat
```

This project uses python, NPM, and the serverless framework (javascript).

If I run this as above it will fail

```
 npm ERR! correctMkdir failed to make directory /.npm/_locks
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! code EACCES
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! syscall mkdir
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! path /.npm
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! errno -13
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! 
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! 
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
2021-03-11 16:17:02  npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1318244366:1318464184 "/.npm"
2021-03-11 16:17:02  make: *** [setup-ci] Error 243
```

I tried many solutions with varying success.  If I add this:
`args '-u root'` to the docker section it works as of course root has permissions to everything.... however security isn't going to like running the docker container as root.

No matter what I do with overriding `$HOME` in `environment or args`, changing users I always end up with permissions issues either with NPMs or python.

Other errors I've encountered with various hacks such as `args '-e HOME=/tmp -e NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/tmp/.npm'`

```
../../../../../tmp/.local/share/virtualenvs/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https-y_ilovXz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:428
2021-03-11 14:45:14    /tmp/.local/share/virtualenvs/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https-y_ilovXz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:428: PytestCacheWarning: cache could not write path /jenkins_home/jenkins-rh7-a01/8b13f8c3/workspace/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https/.pytest_cache/v/cache/nodeids
2021-03-11 14:45:14      config.cache.set("cache/nodeids", sorted(self.cached_nodeids))
```

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/jenkins_home/jenkins-rh7-a01/8b13f8c3/workspace/te_csoe-1624-switch-shared-https/.serverless/cloudformation-template-update-stack.json'
2021-03-11 14:45:19        at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1136:3)
```

Since jenkins mounts random directories to share and random users I am not sure how to modify the Dockerfile for the image to grant write permissions....

Does anyone know how to get the permissions correct?

EDIT added Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
RUN yum install -y unzip
RUN yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
RUN yum install vim-enhanced -y

# install python/pipenv
ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.9
RUN amazon-linux-extras install python${PYTHON_VERSION}
RUN /bin/pip-${PYTHON_VERSION} install pipenv

# install node/npm
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs
RUN mkdir /tmp/node-cache
RUN npm config set cache /tmp/node-cache --global

# install aws-cli2
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install && \
    rm -rf awscliv2.zip
`
# install vault client
ENV VAULT_VERSION=1.5.4
RUN curl -sSLo /tmp/vault.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/$VAULT_VERSION/vault_${VAULT_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip -d /bin /tmp/vault.zip && \
    rm -rf /tmp/vault.zip && \
    setcap cap_ipc_lock= /bin/vault



ADD ./aws-login.sh /usr/local/bin/aws-login.sh
ADD ./ghe-token.sh /usr/local/bin/ghe-token.sh
ENV PATH="/bin:${PATH}"
# indicates CI CONTAINER so processes can check if running in CI
ENV CI_CONTAINER=1
ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
ENV TERM xterm
# avoid million NPM install messages
ENV npm_config_loglevel warn
ENTRYPOINT []
```

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: added dockerfile

Comment: `npm` is trying to write to the root of the folder tree `/.npm/_locks` unless you are running as root this will not work, try specifying `WORKDIR` in your Dockerfile (it should be writable for non root users). This is where all your commands are going to be executed from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that was tripping me up was I had run this as `-u root` many times and I only have one agent (don't ask) and jenkins caches the workspace directory.  So the file permissions had been changed in that code by the docker container running as root.  So when I got rid of `-u root` and it started using the jenkins user it didn't have rights to some files and directories.

The solution was to delete the workspace and make sure that all make calls had an `export HOME=${WORKSPACE}` before any command.

There might be a better way to export HOME but this solves the prob